# How to insert nested JSON arrays into a table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, json

I'm trying to insert a JSON array that came from another JSON array (array of arrays) into a table using `json_populate_recordset()`, but I'm receiving the following error:

> ```
> SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: argument of json_populate_recordset must be an array of objects
> ```

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    j json;
BEGIN
    j := '[[{"a":1,"b":1.23},{"a":2,"b":2.34}],
           [{"a":2,"b":1.23},{"a":3,"b":2.34}],
           [{"a":3,"b":1.23},{"a":4,"b":2.34}]]'::json;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE testj (j json);

    INSERT INTO testj
    SELECT * FROM json_populate_recordset(null::testj, j);

    DROP TABLE testj;
END
$$;
```

The final table should be something like this:

```
                 j                  |
------------------------------------|
[{"a":1,"b":1.23},{"a":2,"b":2.34}] |
[{"a":1,"b":1.23},{"a":2,"b":2.34}] |
[{"a":1,"b":1.23},{"a":2,"b":2.34}] |
```

I'm using a PostgreSQL 9.5 database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your table has only one column of json type where `json_populate_recordset` is aimed at "opening" the JSON structure and put it into a table with the matching columns as keys. So this is probably not the right tool for you. See the `unnest` function instead.

Comment: See: `SELECT unnest(ARRAY['[{"a":1,"b":1.23},{"a":2,"b":2.34}]'::json,
           '[{"a":2,"b":1.23},{"a":3,"b":2.34}]'::json,
           '[{"a":3,"b":1.23},{"a":4,"b":2.34}]'::json])
;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function **`json_array_elements()`** instead, available in Postgres 9.5.
[Quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE), it ...

> Expands a JSON array to a set of JSON values.

And values can in turn be JSON arrays (or any other JSON values).

```
INSERT INTO testj (j)
SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(j);
```